# Untitled Media won't mount multiples in Finder

Tags: finder, apple-silicon, ventura

I work in film. We use gopros a lot and the cards after being reformatted in the GoPro are named "untitled". Before Ventura, I could mount as many untitled cards as I had readers. Finder would label them with 1,2,3 and so on. However, that's not the case anymore. Finder will only mount one of these cards. Even after renaming the card, Finder still won't mount more than one. Any thoughts?